# Defining a static array into a C or C++ source file

Tags: c++, c, arrays, static

I know this is a question that every programmer should know, but I do not know. Long time no C programming and I've forgotten a lot of things.

My question is:

I have three huge static arrays defined inside a header file. Someone told me that It's much better to declare them as `extern` in the header file, and define them in a single C or C++ source file.

How can I do that?

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef _TEMPLE_OBJECT_H_
#define _TEMPLE_OBJECT_H_


#define NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX 10818

static const float TEMPLEVertices[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3] = {...};
static const float TEMPLENormals[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3] = {...};
static const float TEMPLETexCoords[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3] = {...};

#endif
```

If a use a C++ source file, may I need to define a class?

**UPDATE:**
I think the problem is:
Every source file in which those headers are included (even indirectly) will generate its own definition for those static arrays. There's no guarantee that the compiler/linker will optimize them into a single definition, even in source files where they're unused. In fact, in many cases the compiler cannot optimize them away. This could result in your static data consuming a lot of disk space, and possibly runtime memory as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Shoud not be the case for GCC and optimize-enabled build. Here is info on "-fkeep-static-consts" from  
[https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html]https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html
"Emit variables declared static const when optimization isn't turned on, even if the variables aren't referenced.
GCC enables this option by default. If you want to force the compiler to check if a variable is referenced, regardless of whether or not optimization is turned on, use the -fno-keep-static-consts option."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`static` and `extern` at the same time makes no sense. `static` at file scope makes the array inaccessible by other files, while `extern` tells the compiler that your array is defined somewhere else.

You can do what 321008 suggests, *except that you don't declare your arrays static* which is illegal C and C++. That gives you three global variables that you can use wherever the header file is included.

For example like this:

```
// .h file:

extern const float TEMPLEVertices[];

// .cpp (or .c) file:

const float TEMPLEVertices[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 5.6 /* or whatever*/ };
```

Or you can do what fortran suggests, but that will give you file-scope access only, not global variables.

You do *not* in any way have to define a class if you use a C++ source file. Unlike Java, C++ does not force you into an object oriented design (whether or not that is good can probably be discussed, but anyway).

EDIT: As for your question update, that is because you define them as `static`. If you only want global variables, you should not do that, but instead keep one single definition (`const float`) and reference it with `extern`, as per my example above.

Comment: It compiles, but linker throws an error: `undefined reference to `TEMPLEVertices'` and the same for the other two arrays.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that "You do not in any way to have to define a class in a C++ source file."

Comment: @VansFannel: And what is your code? Could you update your question with it, perhaps? Note that you have to include the .h file wherever you want to use the array.

Comment: @VansFannel: then you mis-copied. The provided code must compile and link.

Comment: and @jweyrich: you are right. I've forgotten to add the new C source file to make file. Sorry.

Comment: What if I want to define the content in the `h` file?

Answer (score 7):

Your header file becomes:

```
#ifndef _TEMPLE_OBJECT_H_
#define _TEMPLE_OBJECT_H_


#define NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX 10818

extern const float TEMPLEVertices[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3];
extern const float TEMPLENormals[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3];
extern const float TEMPLETexCoords[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3];

#endif
```

While your source file becomes:

```
// include header
const float TEMPLEVertices[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3] = {...};
const float TEMPLENormals[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3] = {...};
const float TEMPLETexCoords[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3] = {...};

// rest of the source
```

Update: If you are specifying the arrays explicitly, you do not have to mention the sizes. That is you can do:

```
const float TEMPLEVertices[] = {...};
```

or

```
const float TEMPLEVertices[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3];
```

Comment: Thats how you do it! @Øystein: What do you suppose is wrong with it?

Comment: @341008: You cannot use `extern` in a `static` variable, otherwise you'll get a linking error.

Comment: Why are you using `extern const float *TEMPLEVertices` instead of `extern const float TEMPLEVertices[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3]`?

Comment: @VansFannel: Are you trying mine? If so, comment on my answer and tell me what is wrong :) If you are trying the code in the answer above, that is not legal and should fail.

Comment: Sorry guys. Got called away and came back to find so many people laboring over this code snippet. All of you are right. `static` keyword should be dropped (blame copy-paste here). Use []/[n] consistently instead of mixing `[]/*` in header and source (blame me here). Sorry for the confusion. Updated code.

Answer (score 6):

I once saw in the Quake2 source code a funny "trick", that in fact was just an unusual way of using an include:

just do:

```
static const float TEMPLEVertices[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3] = {
#include "TEMPLEVertices.txt"
};
```

etc.

And keep just the data in the included files.

You can still declare them as `extern` in the compilation unit, but this keeps things a little bit tidier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I will get the same problem. I have updated my question with more details about the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple, actually; I'll demonstrate with an easier example, a simple primitive constant.

In your project, you have two files `pi.h` and `pi.cpp`.

The contents of `pi.h` looks like this:

```
#ifndef _PI_H
#define _PI_H

extern const double PI;

#endif
```

The contants of `pi.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include "pi.h"

const double PI = 3.1415926535;
```

If you want to use this constant, you just include `pi.h` where neccessary. The value will always be read from the same location.

The same can be done with pretty much anything - arrays, objects, arrays of objects, STL containers etc. Just be sure to not overuse this technique - especially when the objects declared `extern` are not `const`, you might create some really hard to track side-effects. But for constant data, this is you do it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a simple trick.

a) In every C/CPP file I define *filename*_C
b) In every H/HPP file I define *filename*_H

than...

This is going to be your include file

```
#ifndef _TEMPLE_OBJECT_H_
#define _TEMPLE_OBJECT_H_

#define NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX 10818

#ifdef _TEMPLE_OBJECT_C
const float TEMPLEVertices[NUM_TEMPLE_OBJECT_VERTEX * 3] = {...} ; /* Put here your const values */
#else
extern const float TEMPLEVerticies[] ;
#endif

#endif
```

If I'm not wrong this shoud work (or something very similar to that)... :o)

Comment: I want to put array definitions inside a C or C++ source file.