# Access 2D Pointer-Array

Tags: c, arduino, avr

I have 4 arrays and each has different amount of entries. All these arrays are collected in another one. It's implemented like this:

***Code in a c library***

```
static const int32_t ONE_COLOR[2] = { RGB_BLACK, RGB_WHITE };


static const int32_t TWO_COLOR[4] = { RGB_WHITE, RGB_RED, RGB_GREEN, RGB_BLUE };


static const int32_t THREE_COLOR[8] = { RGB_BLACK, RGB_RED, RGB_GREEN, RGB_BLUE,
    RGB_CYAN, RGB_YELLOW, RGB_MAGENTA, RGB_WHITE };


static const int32_t FOUR_COLOR[16] = { RGB_WHITE, RGB_RED, RGB_GREEN, RGB_BLUE,
    RGB_CYAN, RGB_YELLOW, RGB_MAGENTA, RGB_DARK_RED, RGB_DARK_GREEN,
    RGB_DARK_BLUE, RGB_LIGHT_BLUE, RGB_LIGHT_GREEN, RGB_ORANGE, RGB_LIME,
    RGB_PINK, RGB_LILA };

static const int32_t* COLOR_ARRAY[4] = { ONE_COLOR, TWO_COLOR, THREE_COLOR,
    FOUR_COLOR };
```

How can I access COLOR_ARRAY[1][2] for example?
Thanks for your help :)

**Edit**
Example code for access:

***Code for Arduino***

```
for (i = 0; i < colorsLen; i++) {
            n = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < colorsWrite; j++) {
                    if (bitArray[i * colorsWrite + j] == 1) {
                            n |= 1 << (colorsWrite - 1 - j);

                    }
            }
            colors[i] = COLOR_ARRAY[colorsWrite - 1][n];
// testing access
//              colors[i] = ONE_COLOR[n];
//              colors[i] = n;
    }
```

`colorsLen` is the length of the array `colors` and `colorsWrite` is the amount of bits that can be transmitted with one color.

The purpose is to transmit data via light from a smartphone to an arduino and back. To get more bandwith the data is coded with colors. `colorsWrite` defines how big `colorsLen` should be to get all data transmitted.

Comment: What is the problem with ``COLOR_ARRAY[1][2]`` ?

Comment: I tried it and it compiles. But if I want to access it on my arduino, it dies :( If I access one of the arrays *_COLOR directly it works.

Comment: Does it die giving some error message ? Are you sure that you don't get out of one of the arrays (eg as in ``COLOR_ARRAY[1][33]``) ?

Comment: There are no error messages. But if I replace the access of the array with a fixed value or some of the 'element'-arrays it works fine. There can't be an overflow inside the array itself

Comment: Can you show some more working code ?

Comment: I posted it here for better reading: [link to example code](http://pastebin.com/an6im9iW)

Comment: what is the maximum value of colorsLen and colorsWrite?

Comment: it is min = 1 and max = 4

Comment: Even if I access a fixed value from the array like `colors[i] = COLOR_ARRAY[colorsWrite - 1][0];` the software fails

Comment: I did try the code on PC and it worked, so this is maybe not a generic coding error, i don't have access to full code. Anyway this is a cool project idea, could you please send me an email? (i have an address in my profile)

Comment: I build a small example and it worked on pc and on a small arduino test project. But if the arduino uses the library with the defined arrays it doesn't work. Really strange...

Comment: it looks like email addresses are hidden... ive put my into profile description

Answer (score 0):

Well, judging from your question, you access COLOR_ARRAY[1][2] just like that. So the [1] in that expression is: TWO_COLOR[], and the [2] is: RGB_GREEN. So you do access an array as you did.

I.e: const COLOR clr = COLOR_ARRAY[1][2];

I might be missing some part of your question, but I hope it helps or clarifies.

Regards, 
Øyvind

**EDIT**
This answer might give you a pointer
[Defining a static array into a C or C++ source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645458/defining-a-static-array-into-a-c-or-c-source-file)

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
n |= 1 << (colorsWrite - 1 - j);
```

n will be at least 1, because 1<<0 = 1 ... you are using n as index to `ONE_COLOR[n]` so you cant access the color at index zero which is RGB_BLACK.

Comment: sorry then, maybe if you describe in your question the purpose of those colorsLen and colorsWrite variables?